# Can not run docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

[image]

I use `docker build -t iot .` to build a image
my Dockerfile is :

```
FROM centos
USER root
ADD jdk1.8.0_101.tar.gz /root
COPY  run.sh /etc
RUN chmod 755 /etc/run.sh
CMD "/etc/run.sh"
```

my run.sh is:

```
  #!/bin/bash
    echo "aaaa"
```

I use `docker run -itd iot` to run a container,but I find my container can not be run.
[image]

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your image builds and runs correctly. You just need to remove the `d` flag from run (for detached) or the docker command will exit immediately and run your container in the background. You can see that it actually exited with code zero according to the status column in `docker ps -a`.

You can corroborate this by running `docker logs d63a` (which is your container id). You should see `aaaa`.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is inaccurate. When you `docker run` the container, it normally started, printed `aaaa`, and then exited.

So I guess what you would ask is "why my container cannot keep running, such as a daemon process". This is because you're executing a shell script which is actually a one-shot thing. Modify the `CMD` line in your Dockerfile to `CMD "bash"`, your container will then not exit.

Comment: I changed my Dockerfile as CMD "bash" "/etc/run.sh" and it not work

Comment: Just `CMD "bash"`, without the `"/etc/run.sh"` part.

Comment: I must run run.sh,this is an example,in fact I run my program in run.sh

Comment: OK, forget about my previous suggestion, and append one line to your run.sh: `sleep infinity`

Comment: Your means is that because the run.sh finishes running, the container stops. If run.sh keeps running, the container can run all the time?

Comment: Exactly. The container will exit when the process itself exits.